# How to pull number code from strings buried in parentheses?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, substring

I have string data (`ProductDescription`) that includes product names and ID numbers and need to pull the ID numbers for cross-referencing...

Data Samples:

```
Widget (1234)
Different Widget (123)
Many Widgets (2x) (4567)
```

I am trying to do this with a rather messy `CASE` statement:

```
CASE
    WHEN
        ISNUMERIC(
        SUBSTRING(
            ProductDescription
            ,CHARINDEX('(',ProductDescription)+1
            ,CASE 
                WHEN
                    CHARINDEX(')',ProductDescription)
                        -CHARINDEX('(',ProductDescription)-1 > 0
                    THEN CHARINDEX(')',ProductDescription)
                        -CHARINDEX('(',ProductDescription)-1
                ELSE 0 END
            )) = 1
    THEN
        SUBSTRING(
            ProductDescription
            ,CHARINDEX('(',ProductDescription)+1
            ,CASE 
                WHEN 
                    CHARINDEX(')',ProductDescription)
                        -CHARINDEX('(',ProductDescription)-1 > 0
                    THEN CHARINDEX(')',ProductDescription)
                        -CHARINDEX('(',ProductDescription)-1
                ELSE 0 END
            )
    ELSE 0 END
```

In cases where there is a parenthetic insertion in the product name (as in the "Many Widgets (2x)" example), I end up returning the "2x" value, which is not what I want.

**How can I look for *only* numeric values contained in parentheses and discard the contents of others?** Is there an easier/cleaner way to do the simple `CHARINDEX` work I'm currently attempting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data you need is always at the end of the string, would something like this work?

```
declare @test varchar(200);

set @test= 'Many Widgets (2x) (4567)';

select substring(@test,
                 (len(@test) - charindex('(',reverse(@test))) + 2,
                 charindex('(',reverse(@test)) - 2
                );
```

We can reverse the string, find the first open paren (which is really the last open paren), and go from there.

Comment: Nice thinking about the reversal +1.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your string to XML and use a `cast as xs:int ?` to check if the value is an integer or not.

```sql
declare @T table(C varchar(100));

insert into @T(C) values
('Widget (1234)'),
('Different Widget (123)'),
('Many Widgets (2x) (4567)');

select T.C,
       T2.X.value('(for $n in X return $n/text()[1] cast as xs:int ?)[1]', 'int') as Value
from @T as T
  cross apply (select cast(replace(replace(T.C, '(', '<X>'), ')', '</X>') as xml)) as T2(X)
```

Result:

```
C                          Value
-------------------------- -----------
Widget (1234)              1234
Different Widget (123)     123
Many Widgets (2x) (4567)   4567
```

The XML version of your third string (after the `cast(replace)replace`) looks like this:

```xml
Many Widgets <X>2x</X><X>4567</X>
```

The flwor in the value function walks through the `X` nodes and returns the first value that is an integer.